# .htaccess regex simplification

Tags: regex, .htaccess

i have rewriting part of `.htaccess` like:

```
RewriteRule ^content/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?section=clanky&page=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^content/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?section=clanky&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^content/?$ /index.php?section=clanky [L]
```

Is there any way to make it simplier (one line) to easier modification?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't mind getting blank parameters in your php `$_GET` array, you can just do this:

```
RewriteRule ^content/?(?:([^/]+)/?|)(?:([^/]+)/?|)$ /index.php?section=clanky&page=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

This means if the URI looks like this:

```
/content/123/asd
```

The `$_GET` array will be:

```
Array
(
    [section] => clanky
    [page] => 123
    [id] => asd
)
```

And if it's like this:

```
/content/qwe
```

You'll get:

```
Array
(
    [section] => clanky
    [page] => qwe
    [id] => 
)
```

And if it's:

```
/content/
```

then:

```
Array
(
    [section] => clanky
    [page] => 
    [id] => 
)
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. 
So in PHP I'll have 'only' to use !empty() instead of isset().